# Convergence of $F_2(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, complex-integration

I want to show that i) $F_2(z)=\cfrac{1}{4}\pi i-\cfrac{1}{2}ln2+\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)+\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)^2+\cfrac{1}{3}\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)^3+\ldots$ converges for $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$ and ii) how can I show that $F_2(z)$ is an analytic continuation of the function $F_1(z)=z+\cfrac{1}{2}z^2+\cfrac{1}{3}z^3+\cfrac{1}{4}z^4+\ldots.$?

My first try was demostrate that $F_1(z)$ converges only if $|z|<1$ and later I found that, in general, the function $-ln(1-z)$ represents all the analytic continuations of the function $F_1(z)$. But I have problems with i) and ii).

Any help is welcome and appreciate!

Comment: I note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F_1(x)$ is a geometric series and a power series with the same radius of convergence as $F_1$.  $F_2$ has the same property.